# Is it ok to use a global variable in this case?

Tags: python

So I have a scheduled script that runs continuously. Here's that scheduler script:

```
import os
import schedule
import time

os.chdir("B:\Scheduled_Scripts")

def DSE():
    print("")
    print(colors.OK + '***DSE***')
    try:
        start = time.time()
        exec(open('B:/Scheduled_Scripts/DSE.py').read())
        print("")
        print(colors.OK + "DSE completed successfully in", round(time.time() - start, 2), 'seconds!')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        print(colors.WARNING + 'An error has occurred in DSE.py. It was a ' + type(e).__name__ + '-' + format(e))
        print('')
        pass
```

And now it'll run my DSE.py script where at one point I end up using pandas sql query. I then create a function to start mapping some values.

```
query = '''(my query)'''
price_levels = pd.read_sql_query(query, KORE, params={my_params})

def get_price_level(seat):
    pl = price_levels[price_levels['seatsid'] == seat]['priceleveldesc'].values()
    return str(pl)

DSE_avs['priceleveldesc'] = DSE_avs['seatsid'].map(get_price_level)
```

The problem is that now it won't recognize that 'price_levels' is defined within the function. How frowned upon would it be if I just set price_levels as a global variable?

Comment: `exec(open('B:/Scheduled_Scripts/DSE.py').read())` really? Why not `import DSE`?

Comment: Questions about style / best practices aren't really a good fit for StackOverflow -- we prefer questions with concrete, canonical answers (and, as a general guideline, questions that revolve around a problem or error; if nothing's broken, that's a smell that what you have may not be a SO question). See [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for discussion about one possible alternative and which questions are or aren't a fit on each of the two sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `lambda` to pass `price_levels` as a parameter.

```
query = '''(my query)'''
price_levels = pd.read_sql_query(query, KORE, params={my_params})

def get_price_level(seat, price_levels):
    pl = price_levels[price_levels['seatsid'] == seat]['priceleveldesc'].values()
    return str(pl)

DSE_avs['priceleveldesc'] = DSE_avs['seatsid'].map(lambda s: get_price_level(s, price_levels))
```